# Azure Build Pipelines - jobs are running in a random order

Tags: azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops I have a build pipeline with three Agent Jobs.
On every job I set the value of ***"Run this job***" to ***"Only when all previous jobs have succeeded"***. like this:

[image]

But, actually, the jobs are running in a random order, which means that sometimes the pipeline starts with running the last job first.

How can I determine the run order of the jobs?

Comment: Without the rest of your pipeline definition we cannot say what might be wrong. Guess maybe - know, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run this job** option only works with **Dependencies**. You need to use the **Dependencies** to add a dependency to the previous agent job.

For example I have three agent jobs. They are **Agent job 1**, **Agent job 2**, **Agent job 3**.

[image]

If you want job 1 to run first and then job 2, and at last job 3. You can select Agent job 1 as the dependency for Agent job 2.

Click the dropdown list of Dependencies option of Agent job 2. Select Agent job 1 as the dependency for Agent job 2

[image]

Similarly select the Agent job 2 as dependency for Agent job 3:

[image]

Then you will see the jobs run in the desired order.